I am trying to expose grpc service using nginx in kubernetes. the application is using kestrel in appsettings
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
  name: fortune-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hangfire
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: schedularapi
            port:
              number: 80

and the app service is:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: schedularapi
  labels:
    app: schedularapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: schedularapi
  ports:
  - port: 80         # Host port or pod port that will send request to 50051
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 50051 #container port running GRPC
  type: LoadBalancer 

in app settings we have defined as:
"Kestrel": {
  "EndpointDefaults": {
    "Protocols": "Http2"
  }
},

Getting error when using notification api, requesting the grpc service
500
Undocumented
Error: Internal Server Error

Response body
Download
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
  "title": "Internal server error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
  "traceId": "00-8dae13808379a7f0a01d3935519a6e11-9e7b8b21dca96409-00"
}
Response headers
 cache-control: no-cache,no-store 
 content-type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Thu,19 Sep 2024 09:14:20 GMT 
 expires: -1 
 pragma: no-cache 
 server: Kestrel 
 transfer-encoding: chunked


Please edit your question with proof that that gRPC service is working (you could kubectl -port-forward to the Service and then use e.g. gRPCurl to invoke a method. This will eliminate that from the issue and allow folks to focus on the NGINX|Ingress config.

I'm unfamiliar with NGINX (as an Ingress) but I suspect you can't (!?) use a path prefix with a gRPC service.

Check your logs in your .net service
